# Multiple contexts in Liquibase sql format file

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to use multiple contexts support in Liquibase and I can't achieve the result. My changeset in SQL format looks as follows

```
--changeset bkolasa:1 context:new-db and !edb dbms:postgresql
```

Then when I execute command

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --contexts=new-db,edb --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=jdbc:postgresql://example.com:5432/liqtest?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory --username=liqtest --password=liqtest --changeLogFile=mychangelog.sql update
```

the changeset is still loaded.

My version of Liquibase is 3.2.2.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- changeset istepniak:db-1.14.1 context:dev and test
```

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

`–context=dev,qa` worked for me.
With Liquibase 3.2, support was added to for context expressions in changeSets.
An example: `context=”qa or (dev and release)”`

Newer versions have label which can be used for complex business cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the context at runtime as follows?

`--contexts="new-db and edb"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a change set to be executed in two contexts, namely `dev` and `test`, you probably want to use `or` instead of `and`:

- `or` requires only one of the contexts.
- `and` requires all contexts.

For example, the following change set will be applied in `dev` context, and it will also be applied in the `test` context:

```
-- changeset istepniak:db-1.14.1 context:dev or test
```

Instead, the following change set needs both contexts to be present:

```
-- changeset istepniak:db-1.14.1 context:dev and oracle
```